# Removing a PPTX slide using Apache POI causes 'partName' error on save/write

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

#### Update

For anyone coming here after the fact ... I have not yet resolved the issue BUT, the pseudo code is in fact as follows:

```
XMLSlideShow input = load(blah);
XMLSlideShow s = XMLSlideShow(input.getPackage());

s.removeSlide(15);
s.removeSlide(14);
s.removeSlide(13);
s.removeSlide(12);
s.removeSlide(10);
... etc ...

s.save(some stream);
```

It appears that the process of cloning (passing package into constructor to create a new SlideShow) the whole XMLSlideShow somehow misses something during the clone? Removing the

```
XMLSlideShow s = XMLSlideShow(input.getPackage());
```

and removing slides from the original seems to then delete slides and save consistently without error?

BUT

It seems that at least some slide definitions and images are left in the package (orphaned?) - the PPTX open just fine and you see the slides you expect to see [the subset].

---

#### Issue

I have a scenario where i am using Apache POI (latest v5.2.2) to programatically load, subset (remove slides) and save PPTX files.

I am using the follow pseudo-code:

```
XMLSlideShow s = load(blah);
s.removeSlide(15);
s.removeSlide(14);
s.removeSlide(13);
s.removeSlide(12);
s.removeSlide(10);
... etc ...

s.save(some stream);
```

For some PPTX files, attempting to .removeSlide() on certain slides will cause the following error when SAVING (not at point of removal).

```
Partial stack trace:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: partName
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.removePart(OPCPackage.java:979)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.getOutputStream(PackagePart.java:526)
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.commit(XSLFSheet.java:415)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:467)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:472)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:221)
```

Now I assume that this is related to some kind of corruption of the parts/relations but i cannot find where .. and how to resolve this.

Again, the behaviour is not consistent. For example one slide that fails has one shape that is a simple text block, there is nothing else on the page (the master has an image but not the slide).

Has anyone seen this, and or been able to resolve the matter so this method works consistently for all loaded PPTX files.

Comment: Is the behavior consistent for a given file?

Comment: What `apache poi` version used? Can you upload somewhere a file using which the problem occurs?  And please tell for what slide it appears.

Comment: @Sam - yes it is

Comment: @AxelRichter -5.2.2 version POI (latest released) - I cannot upload the PPTX due to data sensitivity reasons, but will try to somehow produce a mini test case that fails consistently.\